# Is there a shortcut key to 'Split' a transaction in GnuCash?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnucash

When entering transactions in GnuCash 2.4.13, is there a shortcut key to **split** a transaction? My cursor is at either the Debit or Credit colum for the transaction.

Comment: Sorely missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNUCash has all their shortcuts listed on their [wiki](http://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/Keyboard_Shortcuts)

Splitting a transaction does not appear to be apart of their published shortcut keys however they have listed a way on creating custom shortcuts under linux using if this is applicable to you.

Comment: Some more shortcuts are listed here - http://www.gnucash.org/docs/v2.4/C/gnucash-guide/txns-shortcuts1.html

Comment: @matrix Thanks for the extra shortcuts. That page mentions Alt+A, P toggles the split view. Works for me with GnuCash 2.6.12.